# CMake install not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm trying to generate a static library and install it using Cmake and Visual Studio Code, but the files are not installed where I want to.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
Main_Folder    
 - Poly    
 - - CMakeLists.txt    
 - - src    
 - - - Poly.cpp
 - - - Poly.h
 - Test
 - - TestLibs
 - - - TestLibs.cpp
 - - - TestLibs.h
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(poly)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

#Bring the headers, such as Student.h into the project
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

file(GLOB SOURCES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*")

#Generate the static library from the sources
add_library(poly STATIC ${SOURCES})

  #Set the location for library installation                     
  install(
    TARGETS poly
    LIBRARY DESTINATION /Main_Folder/Test/TestLibs/Poly
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION /Main_Folder/Test/TestLibs/Poly
    RUNTIME DESTINATION /Main_Folder/Test/TestLibs/Poly
 )
```

And this is my cmake_install.cmake:

```
# Install script for directory: Main_Folder/Poly
# Set the install prefix
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")
endif()
string(REGEX REPLACE "/$" "" CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")

# Set the install configuration name.
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME)
  if(BUILD_TYPE)
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^[^A-Za-z0-9_]+" "" CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME "${BUILD_TYPE}")
  else()
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME "Debug")
  endif()
  message(STATUS "Install configuration: \"${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}\"")
endif()

# Set the component getting installed.
if(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  if(COMPONENT)
    message(STATUS "Install component: \"${COMPONENT}\"")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT "${COMPONENT}")
  else()
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  endif()
endif()

# Install shared libraries without execute permission?
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE "0")
endif()

# Is this installation the result of a crosscompile?
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
  set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING "FALSE")
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xUnspecifiedx" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  list(APPEND CMAKE_ABSOLUTE_DESTINATION_FILES "/Main_Folder/Test/TestLibs/Poly/libpoly.a")
  if(CMAKE_WARN_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION)
    message(WARNING "ABSOLUTE path INSTALL DESTINATION : ${CMAKE_ABSOLUTE_DESTINATION_FILES}")
  endif()
  if(CMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION)
     message(FATAL_ERROR "ABSOLUTE path INSTALL DESTINATION forbidden (by caller): ${CMAKE_ABSOLUTE_DESTINATION_FILES}")
  endif()
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "/Main_Folder/Test/TestLibs/Poly/" TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY FILES "/home/myUser/git/Main_Folder/Test/TestLibs/Poly/libpoly.a")
endif()
```

The library (libpoly.a) is created, but instead of being installed in /Main_Folder/Test/TestLibs/Poly is found on /Main_Folder/Poly and I dont understand what I'm missing.

I'm using Linux and cmake 3.17.3, I don't know if this might cause the issue.

Comment: `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` shouldn't be set from your project and even less so after the first `project()` command. It's the first `project()` command where this kind of info is used and if you hardcode this, you just limit the ways your project can be used without much benefit. Also does the `Main_Folder` directory in the filesystem root and/or does the user you're running the install from have the permissions to create/write this directory? Does running `cmake --install ...` return 0 as exit code?

Comment: Using absol dest paths is another way you're limiting the uses of your project: basically you won't be able to set up 2 builds for this project without cpack calls overwriting the content, you won't be able to create packages for this project without admin rights on most machines and you cannot keep one version of the lib for use by other projects while also creating packages with an updated version of your lib. Better remove the leading `/` from all destination dirs and use [`set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX / CACHE PATH "...")`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html)